# present ViewController when image inside a cell was pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know how to present the viewController programmatically

I already finished creating a function for tapping of image. My only problem now is how to present the viewController. The image is inside the cell.

ItemsCell.swift

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()

                if let imageStr = obj.image {

                    item.optionImage.kf.setImage(with:URL(string:imageStr))
                    item.optionImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedImage))
                    item.optionImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

                } else {

                    item.optionImage.image = nil

                }
```

The Function:

```
@objc func tappedImage() {

        print("image tapped")

//        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AssetsViewController")

//        controller.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)  
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Post Notification`

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(presentVC(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("PresentVCNotificationName"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc
    func presentVC(_ notification: Notification) {
        let cell = notification.object as? YourCell

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Your Storyboard Name", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your Storyboard ID")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    deinit {
       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}


class Cell: UITableViewCell {

   @objc func tappedImage() {

      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("PresentVCNotificationName"), object: self)
   }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the question states that the image in a table view cell which means the `tappedImage` method is in the cell.

Comment: use the `Post Notification`, see the edit.

Comment: A cell should never know its index path. It's much better to send the cell with the notification. Then the view controller can get whatever information it needs from the cell, including asking the table view view what index path the cell is from. But since the question is closed as a duplicate, you may as well delete your answer.

Comment: you can set the indexPath on the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` function

Comment: But as I said, a cell should never be given its index path. It can change and be wrong.

Comment: IndexPath is represented the data that user selected. I know the cell can be reused and the data of cell can be reset, but if a cell can be tapped by user the data is always the true in this case.

Comment: No. Rows can be inserted, deleted, or moved. This can cause an existing cell's index path to change in the table view but its indexPath property that you set will now be out-of-date. This is why `UITableViewCell` doesn't have an indexPath property. Just send the cell in the notification. It's cleaner and it avoid possible issues.

Comment: You are right. Maintain the IndexPath property correct is difficult and not clean.

Answer (score -1):

In the interface builder tap on the viewController you want to show and make sure you defined a `Storyboard Id`. Create a class for that view controller, and make sure you have an outlet to the `UIImageView` that's supposed to show that image. Also make sure your class has a member of type `UIImage`.

```
// Assumed this class has Storyboard Id of: ImageViewerViewController
class ImageViewerViewController: UIViewController {
   var imageView: UIImageView! // outlet from IB
   var image: UIImage!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      imageView.image = image;
   }
}
```

In the view controller which contains the table:
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    .
    .
    .
    // UITableViewDelegate 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ImageCell) as! YourC ImageCell ellClass
       cell.containerVc = self
       return cell
    }
}

In the cell view:

```
class ImageCell: UITableViewCell {
  weak var containerVc: UIViewController!

  @objc func tappedImage() {
    print("image tapped")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageViewerViewController") as! ImageViewerViewController
    controller.image = item.optionImage.image
    containerVc.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the question states that the image in a table view cell which means the `tappedImage` method is in the cell.

Comment: Yup, that's why before ```tappedImage()``` I clearly stated that it's in the cell view. @rmaddy, this answer exactly answers what the original poster asked.